# How to put a default image in React when I make an API request

Tags: reactjs

Well first hi everybody I'm trying to put the `fallbackImage` when I make a request in the API and the `posterUrl` doesn't load. I have try with conditionals but I think I'm doing wrong

I have to try something like this

```
if(posterUrl === null) {
  return fallbackImage
}
```

and I tried this too on the imp Tag

```
<img src={posterUrl ? posterUrl : fallBackImage/>
```

and when I type in the search bar the `fallbackImage` doesn't render properly
[image]
[image]

Comment: you have fallBackImage and fallbackImage  (lowercase B), on the screen your variable name is dimmed what indicates it is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for `posterUrl || fallbackImage`, but posterUrl will always have partial string and will be truthy in nature.

Instead do like this:

```
const imageUrl = movie.poster_path ? `https://image....${}` : fallbackImage;
```

And you can directly use `imageUrl`

```
<img src={imageUrl} />
```

Comment: HI Kumar and thanks so much it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you are doing it incorrectly? It's absolutely correct. However, you can shorten your code to use fallback image like:

```
<img src={postUrl || fallBackImage} />
```

---

However, if you wish to load fallback image before api loads the request. You can check for it:

```
  <img src={ !loading && postUrl || fallBackImage } />
```

Where, you will set loading to true when api call is completed.